# R programming: I am trying to convert temperature from C to F

Tags: r, statistics, temperature, usage-statistics

I am student working with R programming. I don't have a lot of experience with the software but I am willing to learn.

I am trying to convert temperature values from C to F and assigning the new values to soil_temp_f on a new column. I also intend achieving this with one line of code.

```
# seed germination
seeds <- data.frame(                            
  soil_temp_c = c(17.4, 15.5, 16.5, 15.4, 16.4, 16.3,       
                  16.6, 17.2, 17.5, 15.8, 18.3, 21.0),         
  n_seeds = c(27, 10, 20, 11, 21, 16, 16, 25, 24, 11, 27, 30)   
)

library(ggplot2)                                    
qplot(soil_temp_c, n_seeds, data = seeds)
select(seeds, (soil_temp_c<-soil_temp_c*(9/5)+32)) soil_temp_f)
```

The issue I am facing is on the last line as I keep getting an error that says "Error: unexpected symbol in **select(seeds, (soil_temp_c<-soil_temp_c*(9/5)+32)) soil_temp_f)"**

Comment: You also had two other syntax errors in the code here: (1) your `select(...)` (though Ronak's assertion is correct) should either be followed by a newline `\n` or a semicolon; and (2) the right-paren after `soil_temp_f` is extra, matching nothing in the code here. If that's in *your* script file, than I suggest you pay attention to the paren-matching when editing code in RStudio (if you're using that IDE, of course); if that error is *not* in your script file, then please place make sure the code you give us is the code you are using, otherwise we're hunting the wrong bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` is not the right function to create a new column. Try `transform` in base R

```
transform(seeds, soil_temp_f = soil_temp_c*(9/5)+32)

#   soil_temp_c n_seeds soil_temp_f
#1         17.4      27       63.32
#2         15.5      10       59.90
#3         16.5      20       61.70
#4         15.4      11       59.72
#5         16.4      21       61.52
#6         16.3      16       61.34
#7         16.6      16       61.88
#8         17.2      25       62.96
#9         17.5      24       63.50
#10        15.8      11       60.44
#11        18.3      27       64.94
#12        21.0      30       69.80
```

Or if you want to use `dplyr`, use `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
seeds %>% mutate(soil_temp_f = soil_temp_c*(9/5)+32)
```

Comment: You are a life saver. I have been trying over and over again. Thank you Ronak

Comment: Ronak when I try to call "seeds" I noticed that the soil_temp_f is not showing on the data. I am trying to make it appear permanently on the data set.What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you assign the return-value from `transform` back onto `seeds`? In general, R does not make changes in-place, it is made in a copy and returned. (One notable exception: the `data.table` package.) This means that `transform(seeds,...)` made the change into a copied/new frame and dumped that to the console, without changing the original `seeds`. (Same thing goes for the `dplyr` solution as well.)

Comment: You need to asssign it back `seeds <- transform(seeds, soil_temp_f = soil_temp_c*(9/5)+32)`